# Using a timer to stop another timer

Tags: c#, timer

I am an amateur for C# and I am doing a project.

I have used 3 timers where one is a 20 seconds round timer.
I want that after 20 seconds have passed, the other 2 timers must stop

I am not able to access/call the other 2 timers from the round timer.
Here is the code:

```
public void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{            
    DispatcherTimer tgtTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    tgtTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(tgtTimer_tick);
    tgtTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
    tgtTimer.Start();


    DispatcherTimer txbTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
    txbTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(txbTimer2_tick);
    txbTimer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 4, 000);
    txbTimer2.Start();

    DispatcherTimer rt = new DispatcherTimer();
    rt.Tick += new EventHandler(rt_tick);
    rt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    rt.Start();
}

private void tgtTimer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //some code }

private void txbTimer2_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //some code }

int i = 20 //for the 20 sec round timer

private void rt_tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //round timer
{
    if(i!=0)
    { 
        i--;
        txbTime.Text = "";
        txbTime.Text = Convert.ToString(i) + "s";
    }
    else 
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.3;  

        //tgtTimer and txbTimer2 can't be accessed from here          
    }             
}
```

How should I do stop the 2 timers?

Comment: You'll need a referene to those timers. Easiest way to do that is to have fields on your object that you assign your timer objects to rather than have them as local variables in the method.

Comment: Move this out of the button click: DispatcherTimer tgtTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); Or you can inline the methods for those timers to stay in scope.

Comment: if(i != 0) this will lower your " i " variable also when i is lower than 0 I'm not sure if you want this. Maybe change it to i < 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to add the timers outside of the mouseleftbutton down event like this:

```
        DispatcherTimer tgtTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer txbTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
        DispatcherTimer rt = new DispatcherTimer();


public void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {            
        tgtTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(tgtTimer_tick);
        tgtTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        tgtTimer.Start();



        txbTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(txbTimer2_tick);
        txbTimer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 4, 000);
        txbTimer2.Start();


        rt.Tick += new EventHandler(rt_tick);
        rt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        rt.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Either move the references to your timers out of the button click:

```
DispatcherTimer tgtTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
DispatcherTimer tgtTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer();

public void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{            
        DispatcherTimer tgtTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); //here
        tgtTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(tgtTimer_tick);
        tgtTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        tgtTimer.Start();


        DispatcherTimer txbTimer2 = new DispatcherTimer(); //and here
        txbTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(txbTimer2_tick);
        txbTimer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 4, 000);
        txbTimer2.Start();

        //or inline the method to stay within scope
        DispatcherTimer rt = new DispatcherTimer();
        rt.Tick += (ob, ev) =>
        {
              //still in scope
              txbTimer2.Start();
        };
        rt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        rt.Start();
}
```